# Deleting records with number repeating more than 5

Tags: sql, regex, database, postgresql, pattern-matching

I have data in a table of length 9 where data is like

```
999999969
000000089
666666689
```

I want to delete only those data in which any number from 1-9 is repeating more than 5 times.

Comment: Consecutive digits, or any combination? i.e. does `15552555` get deleted?

Comment: no 15552555 doesn't get deleted...125555555 should be deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be **much simpler** with a regular expression using a [**back reference**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-BRACKET-EXPRESSIONS).

```
DELETE FROM tbl
WHERE  col ~ '([1-9])\1{5}';
```

That's all.

#### Explain

`([1-9])` ...  a character class with digits from 1 to 9, parenthesized for the following back reference.
`\1` ... back reference to first (and only in this case) parenthesized subexpression.
`{5}` .. exactly (another) 5 times, making it "more than 5".

[Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-BRACKET-EXPRESSIONS)

> A *back reference (**\n**)* matches the same string matched by the previous
>   parenthesized subexpression specified by the number **`n`** [...] For example, `([bc])\1` matches `bb` or `cc` but not `bc` or `cb`.

[SQL Fiddle demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/2349)

Answer (score 3):

OK, so the logic here can be summed up as:

- Find the longest series of the same consecutive digit in any given number; and
- Return true if that longest value is > 5 digits

Right?

So, lets split it into series of consecutive digits:

```
regress=> SELECT regexp_matches('666666689', '(0+|1+|2+|3+|4+|5+|6+|7+|8+|9+)', 'g');
 regexp_matches 
----------------
 {6666666}
 {8}
 {9}
(3 rows)
```

then filter for the longest:

```
regress=> 

SELECT x[1] 
FROM regexp_matches('6666666898', '(0+|1+|2+|3+|4+|5+|6+|7+|8+|9+)', 'g') x 
ORDER BY length(x[1]) DESC 
LIMIT 1;

    x    
---------
 6666666
(1 row)
```

... but really, we don't actually care about that, just if any entry is longer than 5 digits, so:

```
SELECT x[1] 
FROM regexp_matches('6666666898', '(0+|1+|2+|3+|4+|5+|6+|7+|8+|9+)', 'g') x 
WHERE length(x[1]) > 5;
```

can be used as an `EXISTS` test, e.g.

```
WITH blah(n) AS (VALUES('999999969'),('000000089'),('666666689'),('15552555'))
SELECT n
FROM blah
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT x[1] 
    FROM regexp_matches(n, '(0+|1+|2+|3+|4+|5+|6+|7+|8+|9+)', 'g') x 
    WHERE length(x[1]) > 5
)
```

which is actually pretty efficient and return the correct result (always nice). But it can be simplified a little more with:

```
WITH blah(n) AS (VALUES('999999969'),('000000089'),('666666689'),('15552555'))
SELECT n
FROM blah
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT x[1] 
    FROM regexp_matches(n, '(0{6}|1{6}|2{6}|3{6}|4{6}|5{6}|6{6}|7{6}|8{6}|9{6})', 'g') x;
)
```

You can use the same `WHERE` clause in a `DELETE`.

Comment: Seems like you forgot about regex back references.

Answer (score 2):

Horrible and terrible in terms of performance, but it should work:

```
DELETE FROM YOURTABLE 
 WHERE YOURDATA LIKE '%111111%' 
    OR YOURDATA LIKE '%222222%' 
    OR YOURDATA LIKE '%333333%'
    OR YOURDATA LIKE '%444444%'
    OR YOURDATA LIKE '%555555%'
    OR YOURDATA LIKE '%666666%'
    OR YOURDATA LIKE '%777777%'
    OR YOURDATA LIKE '%888888%'
    OR YOURDATA LIKE '%999999%'
```

Comment: Actually, performance might not be as bad as it looks, because `LIKE` is still fast when combined with a [trigram index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528). But with that many alternatives, a single regular expression is probably faster, and a lot shorter, of course.