# SQL query to match one of multiple strings

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, sql-like

I have following data in table:

```
+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| subscriber_fields_id | name                                                     | field_type   |
+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|                  143 | Peshawar/Islamabad/Lahore/Swat/Mardan/Karachi            | Job Location |
|                  146 | Karachi                                                  | Job Location |
|                  147 | Lahore and Karachi                                       | Job Location |
|                  149 | Karachi, Mirpur Khas, Sukkur, Layyah, Gilgit, Charsaddah | Job Location |
|                  152 | Islamabad or Lahore                                      | Job Location |
|                  155 | Islamabad                                                | Job Location |
|                  157 | 7 Districts of Sindh and Karachi                         | Job Location |
+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

My query is:

```
select * from subscriberfields
where  name like '%Khairpur,Islamabad,Karachi%';
```

Result:

```
+----------------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+
| subscriber_fields_id | name                                          | field_type   |
+----------------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+
|                  143 | Peshawar/Islamabad/Lahore/Swat/Mardan/Karachi | Job Location |
|                  152 | Islamabad or Lahore                           | Job Location |
|                  155 | Islamabad                                     | Job Location |
+----------------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

It should return all rows where the name includes Islamabad, Khairpur or Karachi but it is not.

Comment: You want `WHERE name LIKE '%Khairpur%' OR name LIKE ...`.  However, it is not sargable and therefore will require a full table scan—it will become desperately inefficient as the table size grows.  You should consider using [fulltext search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch.html) instead.

Comment: Have you tried `SIMILAR TO` like I've suggested in the answer?

Comment: @gudthing: *Never* use `SIMILAR TO`, it's an utterly pointless construct - there is always a better option. I added an answer.

Answer (score 25):

For a proper solution, either [normalize your database design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalisation) or, barring that, consider [full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html).

For a quick solution to the problem at hand, use a [regular expression match (`~`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) or three simple [`LIKE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) expressions:

```
SELECT *
FROM   subscriberfields 
WHERE  name ~ '(Khairpur|Islamabad|Karachi)';
```

Or:

```
WHERE (name LIKE '%Khairpur%'
    OR name LIKE '%Islamabad%'
    OR name LIKE '%Karachi%')
```

.. which can be compressed like [Mario](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10096031/mario-leonel) demonstrates in his answer. Or shorter, yet, with an array literal:

```
WHERE name LIKE ANY ('{%Khairpur%, %Islamabad%, %Karachi%}');
```

But the regexp match gets the same query plan in modern Postgres (can use the same trigram index) and is shorter, yet. See:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

Or use `~*` or `ILIKE` for case-insensitive matching.

Since another answer suggested it: *never* use `SIMILAR TO`:

- [Using SIMILAR TO for a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656452/using-similar-to-for-a-regex/24659766#24659766)
- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

Answer (score 5):

You can use this:

```
select * from subscriberfields
where  name like any(array['%Khairpur%','%Islamabad%','%Karachi%']);
```

https://postgres.cz/wiki/PostgreSQL_SQL_Tricks#LIKE_to_list_of_patterns

Answer (score 3):

Try using `SIMILAR TO` like below:

```
SELECT * FROM subscriberfields 
WHERE name SIMILAR TO '%(Khairpur|Islamabad|Karachi)%';
```

Also you should read up on database normalization. Your design could and should definitely be improved.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL try using a regular expression "REGEXP" and operator | which works like OR:

```
SELECT * FROM subscriberfields  WHERE  name REGEXP 'Khairpur|Islamabad|Karachi';
```

so you will get results containing at least one of these words.

Alternatively, if you want results that will include ALL words, use:

```
SELECT * FROM subscriberfields  WHERE  name REGEXP '(?=.*Khairpur)(?=.*Islamabad)(?=.*Karachi)';
```

Works with MySQL on server version 10 MariaDB and PHP 8

If you want to learn more about REGEXP try:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-regular-expressions-regexp/
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/sql-contains-string-sql-regex-example-query/

There are many blogs with REGEXP examples, but not everyone will give you all the patterns and values you can use, but for starters, have a look at these.

Answer (score -1):

Use OR in WHERE clause, like,

```
select * from subscriberfields where name like '%Khairpur%' OR name like '%Islamabad%' OR name like '%Karachi%';
```

Hope it works.

Comment: no, the value is coming from database, i cannot split it by commas because sometimes it is split by , , /, - etc.

Comment: @MTaqi: This sounds like very poor database design indeed.  You may like to read up to [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and also take a look at [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462)

Comment: In that case you really need to consider **FULLTEXT Searching**, as suggested by **eggyal**.